# Firebase rules acting very strange

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Hello to everyone reading this.

I am coding a flutter app for an hospital, that has this db structure.

[image: Database Model]

I am having an issue fetching sessions data, exactly the following document.

[image: Document that i am trying to request]

Using the following method to get the lastSession a therapist made, using his therapistUID as the filtering field.

```
Future<Session> getLastSession() async {
 Query query;
 query = Firestore.instance
     .collection("sessions")
     .where("therapistUID",
         isEqualTo: this.uid)
     .orderBy("date", descending: true)
     .limit(1); //this.uid = auth uid of current therapist.
 try {

  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.getDocuments(); //exception thrown here

  if (querySnapshot.documents.isEmpty) {
    throw Exception("Empty query");
  } else {
    lastSession = Session.fromDocument(querySnapshot.documents[0]);
    return lastSession;
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw Exception("cannot get data from database");
}}
```

with the following rules

```
rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

match /patients/{document=**} {
  allow read,write,list: if checkPatientAccess(resource.data);
}

match /therapists/{document=**} {
  allow read,write,list: if checkOwnership();
}

match /sessions/{document=**} { 
    allow read, write,list: if checkPatientAccess(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/patients/$(resource.data.patientUID)).data);
}

match /devices/{document=**} {
    allow read, write,list: if false;
}

match /clinics/{document=**} {
    allow read, write,list: if false;
  }}}

function checkOwnership(){
  return resource.id == request.auth.uid;
}

function checkPatientAccess(patient){
  return request.auth.uid in patient.therapistUIDs;
}
```

Code is throwing this exception

[image: Exception]

Does anyone know why is it rejecting the query? keep in mind query is only one document, and as well there is only one document in the database that could fit those filters. Using testlab with same parameters works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase security rules do not on their own filter data, as that would not scale. This becomes clear when we look at:

```
match /sessions/{document=**} { 
    allow read, write,list: if checkPatientAccess(get(/databases/$(database)/documents/patients/$(resource.data.patientUID)).data);
}
function checkPatientAccess(patient){
  return request.auth.uid in patient.therapistUIDs;
}
```

In order to secure your read operation, these rules would have to load each document and check the `therapistUIDs` value in there. This would be an O(n) operation, while Firestore is guaranteed to return results on O(1). For this reason, such security rules don't work.

Your rules **do** work for reading a single document, but not for the `list` operation.

If you can come with with a query that returns the data that you want, you may be able to secure that query. But since Firestore doesn't support any type of join in queries, you'd need to replicate the data you want to filter on from the `patient` document into each `session` document in order to make this work.

---

As discussed in the comments: Since your query ensures all documents have the same `patientUID`, the `get()` call in your rules is guaranteed to always get the same document, and thus the rules engine can guarantee that it will never return an authorized document for the query.

Pretty nifty actually.

Comment: Is it strange that those rules work using another parameter? like patientUID? because it works using that. (Getting last session for a patient)

Comment: As said: it **will** work for fields that are in the documents you're reading, because the rules engine is smart enough to check that when your listener is attached. But it can't do that for other documents, as it'd have to actively check those documents.

Comment: but that's the same method, same rules, same rules flow. 
using a where("patientUID", equals: uid) works instead of where("therapistUID", equals: uid)

I am sorry to ask you again but for me this is strange, it should give error both ways.

Comment: I get the explanation regarding the document that should be existing and cannot be checked every time, and I am very thankful about that, that's more clear now.
But i don't explain this attitude.

Comment: You said "(Getting last session for a patient)" I assume it means you're getting a single document. In that case the rules engine **does** actually read that one document, because it can guarantee how long it takes. See the second paragraph in my answer too.

Comment: that's using the same method, using a query with one document limit. Why does it not work when getting it for a therapist?, it should be the same operation but using a different field, btw database only has 1 session document.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/devdanetra/3716dd3098b3dab5409be003b11c6d4f that's the working code for the patient, this works.

Comment: As far as I underwstand/see, that is still a query - so it should behave the same. I recommend splitting `list` and `get` rules, to pinpoint which one is being triggered.

Comment: well, this is very strange, is using list  (it gives no permission if list is false, gives result if list is true), on the query using therapistUID and seems to be using get if i use patientUID (it gives result even if list is false)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/devdanetra/38b70e5d752f5683a09690e676c4f822

Comment: Is the query where you filter on `patientUID` coming from the local cache by any chance? If that's the case, an uninstall/reinstall will fix the issue (logic being that you can't unsee something that the client has seen already).

Comment: No it's not, first run. Fresh install

Comment: I actually just figured it out. Since your query ensures all documents have the same `patientUID`, the `get()` call in your rules is guaranteed to always get the same document, and thus the rules engine can guarantee that it will never return an authorized document for the query.  Since your non-working query uses a different field for its condition, the `get()` call may point to different documents for different results - so it can't statically guarantee that it'll only return authorized documents. Pretty nifty actually.

Comment: That's actually a very good explanation, now it's clearer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But if so, it should be specified in the Queries docs, because it's very confusing at first time.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how many documents you request - Firestore security rules [will not act as a filter on those documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Please read and understand this documentation.  It won't let you conditionally check something for each document to determine if it can be read.  Your rules are trying to express that something must exist in a matching patient document for each session read, but that's not allowed.  It simply will not scale the way that Firestore requires, and would be extremely costly for queries with large result sets.

Comment: yes, but i am only requesting documents that i know have a matching document existing, is it still wrong to do?

Comment: That doesn't matter.  The rules don't know that.  You can't override the behavior of the rules.